# package com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs does not exist when runing javac on GridDB java connection file

Tags: griddb

While trying to test my connection.java file which contain my Fixed Mode GridDB connection using the below command;

```
javac java-api/Connection.java
```

I got the following errors;

> java-api/Connection.java:4: error: package com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs does not exist
> import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.Container;
> ^
> java-api/Connection.java:5: error: package com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs does not exist
> import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.Collection;
> ^
> java-api/Connection.java:6: error: package com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs does not exist
> import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.GSException;
> ^
> java-api/Connection.java:7: error: package com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs does not exist
> import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.GridStore;
> ^
> java-api/Connection.java:8: error: package com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs does not exist
> import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.GridStoreFactory;
> ^
> java-api/Connection.java:9: error: package com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs does not exist
> import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.Query;
> ^
> java-api/Connection.java:10: error: package com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs does not exist
> import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.Row;
> ^
> java-api/Connection.java:11: error: package com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs does not exist
> import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.RowKey;
> ^
> java-api/Connection.java:12: error: package com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs does not exist
> import com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.RowSet;
> ^
> java-api/Connection.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
> public static void main(String[] args) throws GSException{
> ^
> symbol:   class GSException
> location: class Connection
> java-api/Connection.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
> GridStore store = GridStoreFactory.getInstance().getGridStore(props);
> ^
> symbol:   class GridStore
> location: class Connection
> java-api/Connection.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
> GridStore store = GridStoreFactory.getInstance().getGridStore(props);
> ^
> symbol:   variable GridStoreFactory
> location: class Connection
> java-api/Connection.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
> Container<Object, Row> container = store.getContainer("device1");
> ^
> symbol:   class Container
> location: class Connection
> java-api/Connection.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
> Container<Object, Row> container = store.getContainer("device1");
> ^
> symbol:   class Row
> location: class Connection
> 14 errors

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this following the griddb.org [documentation](https://griddb.org/docs/2_quickstart_guide/2.md_quickstart_guide/md_quickstart_guide/) by adding the gridstore.jar path to the CLASSPATH environment variable using the command below;

```
export CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:/usr/share/java/gridstore.jar:.
```